# MYSQL Query $result[x] stopped working

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql query in my mysql include file sql.php :

```
    $resultid = array();
    $sqlstring9 = "SELECT * FROM auswahl_time WHERE IsActive = 1 ORDER BY Time_PKey ASC";

    $resultid[9] = mysql_query($sqlstring9);    
    $resultid10 = mysql_query($sqlstring9);
```

On my index page :

```
echo mysql_num_rows($resultid[9]);
echo mysql_num_rows($resultid10);
```

returns only the result for $resultid10 not $resultid[9]. I got this to work before and im not sure what changed since then. What are the requirements for this to work? Do i need to initialize the array for resultid in every script?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking, but why are you using `$resultid[9]` and not `$resultid[10]`?

Comment: Please add `var_dump(mysql_query($sqlstring9));` to your code and post the results. This will show all results of your query and will help in debugging why it's not working as you expect.

Comment: im using an array because in index i use something like this :                   for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++ ) {  echo $resultid[$i]; }

Comment: $sqlstring9 = "SELECT * FROM auswahl_time WHERE IsActive = 1 ORDER BY Time_PKey ASC";
 var_dump(mysql_query($sqlstring9));                                                           Returns this :   resource(26) of type (mysql result)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sqlstring9 = "SELECT * FROM auswahl_time WHERE IsActive = 1 ORDER BY Time_PKey ASC";

$resultid = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sqlstring9));

echo $resultid[9];
echo $resultid[10];
```

Comment: When using mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlstring9) i get this error :   PHP Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\service_report\sql.php on line 135.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the mysql_query function

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, turns out i had another unrelated query called $resultid. After renaming it it worked.